# Ajax error when uploading image

Tags: forms, media, files

I have a problem on my Drupal website since 2 days. When I try to add a new image (50 KB), the thumbnail is not displayed after transferring the image so I have to save the element and open it again to see the cropping box. I checked the ajax response and I found this error:

> An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (64 MB) that this server supports.

I did some search on Drupal forums and SE, tried all the solutions but still have the same issue. This is my current configuration:

> Drupal 7.19
>
> Nginx 1.6.2
>
> PHP 5.3.24
>
> post_max_size = 64 MB
>
> upload_max_filesize = 64MB

I'm not using the nginx progress module

Please note that I have another copy of the website used for development and hosted in the same server with the same nginx and php settings. This copy works perfectly.

Any suggestion on what to do to fix this issue?

Comment: What's in webserver' s error log? Something must be different between instances, and you are the only one who can check what is it.

Comment: What do you have for `client_max_body_size` in your nginx conf?

Comment: @Clive: client_max_body_size 32m

Comment: @Mołot: nothing related to that in /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: you don't actually list what you have tried, so here's a couple of questions based on my own experiences with this error: are you running jquery update module, and if so at what version? do you have a proper temp folder, with proper permissions? are your public/private folders set up correctly with proper permissions? is the install in a sub-folder, and if so is it set correctly in the settings.php file?